# Getting an object with maximum array length for a given property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to get an object having a property with the longest array length from an array objects.

```
[ {a:[...],...}, {a:[...],...}, ... } ]
```

Lodash has `maxBy` to get the object with `property` having max value but I want to check the length of the property's array. My object also has a `getCount()` function but that doesn't work either so I guess it's because lodash can only check property's numeric value. Can lodash's `maxBy` use the length of an array as the condition somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`_.maxBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#maxBy):

```js
let arr = [{a: [1]}, {a: [1,2]}, {a: [1,2,3]}];

// with a lambda
console.log(_.maxBy(arr, obj => obj.a.length));

// with `_.property` iteratee shorthand
console.log(_.maxBy(arr, 'a.length'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.reduce() works well for this type of thing.  Something like:

```js
const arr = [{a: [1]}, {a: [1,2]}, {a: [1,2,3]}];

const result = arr.reduce( (e1, e2) => e1.a.length>e2.a.length ? e1: e2 );

console.log( "Element of arr having longest a:", result );
```

The Array.reduce method calls the function you give it with arguments for the 'result so far' (e1) and the current element (e2).  In this case your function simply returns the one with the longest 'a'.

Nicest thing is there's no library dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Math.max` and `map`

```js
let arr = [{a: [1]}, {a: [1,2]}, {a: [1,2,3]}];

let op = Math.max(...arr.map(({a})=>a.length))

console.log(op)
```